# AML Studio: Register mutliple gateways on the same server

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am struggling to find a way to register multiple gateways. I have a local instance of my SQL server and have created a gateway to access to it from the AML Studio workspace. It works fine but now I would like to access to the same SQL server instance from another workspace. So the question is: how to register a new gateway without removing the previous one?
I followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/use-data-from-an-on-premises-sql-server).
Does the following explanation mean that there is no way to do that?

> You can create and set up multiple gateways in Studio for each workspace. For example, you may have a gateway that you want to connect to your test data sources during development, and a different gateway for your production data sources. Azure Machine Learning gives you the flexibility to set up multiple gateways depending upon your corporate environment. Currently you can’t share a gateway between workspaces and only one gateway can be installed on a single computer.

It is quite limiting as connecting to the same server from multiple workspaces may be sometimes crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I have found a way to bypass this limitation. From this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/use-data-from-an-on-premises-sql-server) I have found that:

> The IR does not need to be on the same machine as the data source. But staying closer to the data source reduces the time for the gateway to connect to the data source. We recommend that you install the IR on a machine that's different from the one that hosts the on-premises data source so that the gateway and data source don't compete for resources.

So the  logic is pretty simple. You provide access to your local server to another machine on vpn and install your gateway there. Important: I have set up the firewall rules on the server before, to be able to establish the connection remotely.